# Color printing in emacs without X11

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, batch-processing, x11

I'm using ps-print-buffer-with-faces to print out code with colored syntax highlighting (in emacs).

This works fine if I call ps-print-buffer-with-faces interactively (using M-x for example). I've also got it working from a bash script so that I can print in color from the command line. No problem.

However, I want to be able to perform this from cron, or possibly from a Makefile (i.e. without X11)

I've tried using the emacs -nw option and it complains that stdin is not from a tty and will not continue.

When I use the emacs --batch option, it appears that it is working, but the resulting postscript file has no colors at all.

Does anyone know how I can get ps-print-buffer-with-faces to obtain colors without X11?

Comment: Just an idea: could you set the TERM environment variable in the Makefile before calling emacs --batch?

Comment: Yes, I did try that. This is what I have to do to get it working from my bash script, and it does allow me to do colors. But when I run it from cron (even with TERM set) it doesn't work. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

This really bring back some memories -- I wrote a package like that back in the 1990:s, unfortunately, I have lost the source code (this was long before I started using a version control system).

The key to using font-lock in batch mode is to fool it into believing that it's in interactive mode, by setting `noninteractive` to nil.

I just threw together the following, is saves a postscript file named ORIGINAL_BASENAME.ps. You can easily modify this to print to the printer directly, by not passing the file name parameter.

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script
(defun ps-batch-print (files)
  (dolist (source files)
    (unless (file-exists-p source)
      (user-error "File not found: %s" source))
    (find-file source)
    (let ((noninteractive nil))
      (font-lock-mode 1))
    (ps-print-buffer-with-faces (concat (file-name-nondirectory
                                         (file-name-sans-extension source))
                                        ".ps"))))

(ps-batch-print command-line-args-left)
```

As always, Emacs packages print tons of messages irrelevant when in batch mode. You can get rid of them by redirecting stderr using `2> /dev/null`, if you are using a UNIX-like system.

Comment: I'm setting it as you suggest, and then echoing back out whether or not it's interactive and it still thinks it's non-interactive when I run it in batch mode. So, this is the right idea, but the wrong way to 'trick' it. Any other ideas or documentation you might be able to point me to for tricking emacs to think it's being called interactively?

Comment: @jrel, did you try my script, did't it work? (I tried it before I posted it and I successfully generated a postscript file.) Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: I first tried using your 'trick' alone (setting noninteractive to nil) in my existing code, and it didn't work. I tried cut & paste of your code directory and it is working just fine (as you said). So I'm going to integrate your code as-is and get it set up. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: So after integrating your code into my system, I now see the problem. Your code works for syntax foreground colors, but it does not work for background colors. The code I'm trying to highlight has text with non-white background (and black foreground) so that specific lines are highlighted. If I switch the fore/back ground colors, they show up. So your trick half works for me, but is not a full solution. But thank you for the helpful answer.

Comment: @jrel, I'm glad that you managed to get it to work, or at least take one step closer to a solution. One question, did you have the same problem when printing from an interactive Emacs? I'm just curious as I don't see how my code could change the behaviour of ps-print.

Comment: No, I don't think it's your code at all. I looked over the ps-print source code, and it's pretty clear that it needs x11 running to correctly populate the information for tying face color codes to color values inside the postscript file. It's no surprise that using the --batch doesn't work with colors at all. Your trick does seem to half-work, with the foreground postscript colors, but just not the background colors. So your solution will work fine as long as you only want foreground text coloring. And yes, the background coloring works fine when I don't use --batch. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, it's not a printer issue. I did a diff on the postscript files themselves between interactive and your code. I can see the markup for each face is in the postscript, but the background color values don't ever change when using --batch. I can modify and verify the foreground colors just fine. And when using interactive mode, I can see both the foreground and background postscript markups change accordingly.

Comment: I guess that that would make sense. When in batch mode, Emacs thinks it only has a handful of colors, typically either 8 or 256 (depending in the setting of the TERM environment variable). I am in the process of finishing another package where I emit ANSI sequences from face information -- in that package I basically had to replicate the entire face selection process and color system in elisp. (https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi in case you're interested.)

Comment: One more thing, I think that running in batch mode is more or less equivalent to running in "no window" more in a terminal. You can use this to set up your package to work in this mode before you continue with batch mode.